# Bash read and wait even after input

Tags: bash, wait

In bash I want to read a key input from user and wait even after key was pressed.
I use

```
read -n 1 -s -t 0.05 key
```

but after input it stops waiting. I want to wait 0.05 no matter what and store first key pressed in variable key.

Comment: put a `sleep 0.5` after your `read`? Good luck.

Comment: I tried it but in my program i scan input every 0.05 seconds and if I use sleep it will print key in terminal and it is not what i want and also. If there would be someting like silent sleep it could be ok.

Comment: Are you really hellbent on using shell for this? I'm thinking a Python script would probably be a better approach. Bash is good for many things but this isn't one of them.

Comment: that's exercise I have to do :(

Comment: Depending on what you are hoping to accomplish, maybe you could constrain stdin to max 2000 bytes per second? See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/how-to-throttle-per-process-i-o-to-a-max-limit

Comment: What do you mean by silent sleep? The `sleep` command does not produce any output ...

Comment: The value of key is printed by `read` not sleep. For example, `read -e -p "Select an option: " choice && sleep 10` will print the message and the value of `choice`, while if you add the `-s` the value of choice is not printed. `sleep` does not produce any output.

Comment: I know sleep doesn't print anything but if you press a button while sleep it will print this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, use `sleep`. Everything entered during `sleep` will be printed on the terminal (as for every command that doesn't consume stdin). Use `stty` to hide this output.

- `stty -echo` disables output.
- `stty echo` enables output (unconsumed characters hidden so far will be printed).

You probably want to wait only the remaining time and not an additional 0.05 seconds. There are two ways to do so:

## The easy but possibly unreliable way

Use `sleep` *before* `read` — that way you neither have to measure the wait time nor have to compute the remaining time:

```
stty -echo
sleep 0.049
read -n1 -s -t0.001 key;
stty echo;

echo "key was $key"
```

The timeout `read -t…` must be long enough to actually read the buffered characters. You can test this by copy-pasting a very long line into your terminal – `read` will only read a part of it. On a slow system you may have to increase `0.001`. But keep in mind that the combined waiting time for the user can be just the sleep time, that is, a bigger `-t` means less precision.

## The complicated but robust way

To circumvent that problem you can put `sleep` *after* `read` and compute the remaining waiting time, which of course is more work. Here is a solution in `bash` 5.0 or higher:

```
# all variables of the form tSomething are in μs = 10^-6 s
stty -echo
tStart="${EPOCHREALTIME/./}" 
read -n1 -s -t0.05 key;
tEnd="${EPOCHREALTIME/./}"
printf -v tWait %07d "$((tStart + 50000 - tEnd))" # 50000 μs = 0.05 s
sleep "${tWait:: -6}.${tWait: -6}"
stty echo

echo "key was $key"
```